# Why does this cross-domain ajax call actually work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, cross-domain

I inadvertently wrote a cross-domain AJAX call to [NextBus](http://www.nextbus.com/xmlFeedDocs/NextBusXMLFeed.pdf) (with jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=predictions&a=sf-muni&r=1&s=6294',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function(data) {
           do_stuff();
      }
});
```

Thing is, it works on all browsers, despite coming from a different domain. Given the Single Origin Policy, **why does this actually work?**

The page is here: http://sftransitfirst.org/F/, selecting a stop from the pull-down triggers the ajax.

As expected, making a similar call to the [Google Maps API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) fails with the familiar `Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (and it doesn't support jsonp).

Comment: I think it's because the Google URL is "https"? Not sure tho

Comment: The set of response headers from that URL contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. [CORS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: @Rob Just write it as an answer;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They must have explicitly allowed cross-domain access, with something of this manner:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Or with htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I thought the SOP was a client-side (browser) security measure, though. Allowing the remote webservice to override the policy seems to defeat the purpose, doesn't it? i.e. that you shouldn't trust any old resource from another domain.

Comment: @carillonator In the first place, SOP prevents scripts from different origins to access each others methods and properties thus e.g. preventing a third party script from reading the cookies your script has set.

Comment: @carillonator I can see where it would seem like a security risk. But this kind of setting will(should) only be enabled on sites that want there content accessible (eg, twitter). And from a security point of view the site you're viewing would also have to be making a call to that site which has allow-origin all allowed. So from a "hacker" worry point of view, access would already be needed to either insert the call to other site, or enable the access in the root, either of which the sites security has already been hugely compromised.

Answer (score 5):

Many modern web APIs enable [Cross-Domain Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS). CORS is a method for websites to voluntarily make their pages available to cross-domain scripts.  The [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) HTTP header from the server signals to your web browser that it is okay to allow the script to access the page with Ajax, even if the script is running on a different origin.  If the server does not serve CORS headers, your browser will enforce the SOP as usual.

Most APIs choose to expose their pages to cross-domain scripts because they know that virtually all of their users will want to be able to access the API via Ajax from their own domains.