# ajax request error but no error in firebug

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have following ajax code in which i'm making a `GET` request to a url and retrieving webpage (html) response.

FYI: firefox_v_26

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({

        url: "http://zenhabits.net",

        type: "GET",

        dataType : "html",

        success: function( data ) {
            alert("success")
        },

        error: function( xhr, status ) {
            alert("error");
        },



});
</script>
```

it is alerting with error message.
But when i traced the request in firebug, response is `200`. according to firebug i have made the request successfully.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Is the data coming back not HTML?

Comment: incorrect dataType is most likely the culprit

Comment: i want to retrieve a web page, dataType has to be "html" , right?correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Just wondering, is page on same domain?

Comment: the url is pointing to the home page. that page i want to fetch

Comment: But are you running this code fetching `http://zenhabits.net` on a page from `http://zenhabits.net`?

Comment: no. It is from a local html page

Comment: alert(""error"); <== :P

Answer (score 1):

Please Write this in your code

```
error: function( xhr, status ) {
            console.log("xhr : "+xhr+" Status: "+status);
        }
```

then after Ajax call you check error in firebug or instead make a break point in error function 
At finally locate error message

I am almost sure you made a Cross Domain request, **What is Cross Domain?** 
It allows you to make a request to another domain
For example when you call Ajax from localhost to http://zenhabits.net you make a cross domain request,
OR even when you make an Ajax call from sub domain to main domain, you make a cross domain request.
See this example:
Suppose I am developing an Ajax request for "api.jquery.com" within "api.jquery.com" sub domain and not the main domain which is "www.jquery.com". The returned value is "success" , but if you go to "www.jquery.com" and again call this request you get "error" because you had a cross domain request

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://api.jquery.com",
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "html",
        success: function( data ) {
            alert("success")
        },
        error: function( xhr, status ) {
            alert("error");
        }
});
```

Comment: When you log xhr show this :  
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error", more...}  
Click on the object and see responseText

Comment: Just add this in error function  console.log(xhr); then check responseText

Comment: Please check again above answer

Comment: ajax request to http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Fight Club which returns json response it is successful. This also a cross domain, right?

Comment: Where you call Ajax request from?

Comment: in both cases from a local html file

Comment: Yes it is cross domain,Why are Ajax HTTP Requests not allowed to cross domain boundaries? Because AJAX requests are  submitted with **user credentials**, and allow the caller to read the returned data,
but cross-domain AJAX that omits user credentials.
now you say how to works your cross domain? for answer you  can see this page :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162687/why-does-this-cross-domain-ajax-call-actually-work